# Can I create objects (like rectangles) with commands in Powerbuilder?

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder, tetris

I'm trying to program Tetris with powerscript. Don't ask why, but I would know, if I could create random objects in powerbuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create these types of objects within a datawindow control.  Generally this would be a series of 'Modify' statements.  Here is one example from the PowerBuilder help:

> string modstring
>
> modstring = 'create rectangle(Band=background X="206" Y="6"
>   height="69" width="1363" brush.hatch="6" brush.color="12632256"
>   pen.style="0" pen.width="14" pen.color="268435584" background.mode="2"
>   background.color="-1879048064" name=rect1 )'
>
> dw_cust.Modify(modstring)

This creates a rectangle in the background of a datawindow.  If you need to move the thing you would have to set up a timer and then change the x and y properties appropriately.

To create a Tetris type game in PB would be quite an achievement.  I've made games with PB before but none which had the movement complexity of Tetris.

Comment: I try this out. Thank you :-)